# How to get number of rows found from retrieved results?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to get the results from a database along with how many total rows found with it, how many rows found on WHERE status = 1 and how many rows found on WHERE  status = 0.

**This is my query**

```
$this->db->query('SELECT id, book_title, tag, book_no, status FROM books WHERE tag LIKE :key');
    
$this->db->bind(':key', "%$key%");
```

Comment: You need to run another query to get total count. Or you can use php count() function on received resultset to get count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to get this but I am not sure this is the proper method for this. If it is not proper method please explain me

```
$this->db->query('SELECT id, book_title, tag, book_no, status,
                (SELECT count(*) FROM books WHERE tag LIKE :key) AS total_books,
                (SELECT count(*) FROM books WHERE tag LIKE :key AND status = 1) AS total_available_books 
                FROM books WHERE tag LIKE :key');

$this->db->bind(':key', "%$key%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for, but you can use below sql query if you are interested in getting the count of records with status = 1 and status = 0.

```
select status, count(id) from books where status in (0,1) group by status;
```

Comment: its simple how many rows found on my executed query. and in your query how i can return and display the no of rows by status 1 and 0?